# How to configure waiting time for LUKS password

Tags: linux, luks, disk-encryption

My `/home` partition (on Linux Debian testing) is encrypted with LUKS.

```
$ mount|grep home
/dev/mapper/home-crypt on /home type ext4 (rw,relatime)
```

Configuration via `/etc/crypttab`:

```
home-crypt UUID=830807e5-01fb-4d82-b2ce-c2e51b176560 none luks,timeout=180
```

During boot, the LUKS password to decrypt my `home` partition is required via prompt. But **this prompt is mixed among other kernel/system logs**.

How to add a **waiting time** so that this prompt is displayed after all others logs during boot ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delay the mounting of the LUKS-encrypted partition by specifying a systemd service unit that waits for a set time before proceeding with the unlocking and mounting.

1. Create a custom systemd service file, for example `/etc/systemd/system/delay-luks-prompt.service`, and add the following content:

```bash
[Unit]
Description=Delay for LUKS prompt
After=local-fs.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/sleep 30
Type=oneshot

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

This will cause a delay of 30 seconds.

2. Add this custom service as a dependency for the `systemd-cryptsetup@home-crypt.service` to ensure it waits for the delay:

Edit the `/lib/systemd/system/systemd-cryptsetup@.service` file and locate the `[Unit]` section. Add the line:

```bash
After=delay-luks-prompt.service
```

Your `[Unit]` section might then look like:

```bash
[Unit]
Description=Cryptography Setup for %I
Documentation=man:systemd-cryptsetup@.service(8) man:crypttab(5)
DefaultDependencies=no
Conflicts=umount.target
Before=umount.target
After=cryptsetup-pre.target
After=delay-luks-prompt.service
BindsTo=dev-mapper-%i.device
...
```

3. Enable and start the custom service:

```bash
systemctl enable delay-luks-prompt.service
systemctl start delay-luks-prompt.service
```

4. Regenerate your initramfs:

```bash
update-initramfs -u
```

5. Reboot and test.

This should result in the LUKS password prompt for your `/home` partition being delayed by 30 seconds, allowing other boot logs to display first.

**REMEMBER TO BACK UP FILES BEFORE DOING CHANGES**

Comment: Thanks for you detailed response.On my Debian Linux testing distribution, I haven't `/lib/systemd/system/systemd-cryptsetup@.service` but only a `/run/systemd/generator/systemd-cryptsetup@home\x2dcrypt.service` automatically generated by `systemd-cryptsetup-generator`. Can I modify it to add dependency to your custom systemd service file (delay LUKS prompt) ?

Comment: I modified my `systemd-cryptsetup@home\\x2dcrypt.service` (systemd Unit file generated by `systemd-cryptsetup-generator`) via `systemctl edit --full systemd-cryptsetup@home\\x2dcrypt.service` to add `delay-luks-prompt.service`.